# $ P( A \mathrel{\triangle} B ) \le P(A \mathrel{\triangle} C) + P(B\mathrel{\triangle} C)$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, self-learning, lebesgue-measure

Show that $$ P( A \mathrel{\triangle}  B ) \le  P(A \mathrel{\triangle} C)  + P(B\mathrel{\triangle}C)$$
where $\mathrel{\triangle}$ indicates the symmetric difference

I cannot write my idea, because it's trivial. Please how to show this inequality. Thank you for helping.

Comment: show that $A \trig B \subset  (A \trig C) \cup (B \trig C)$.

Comment: why down-voted ?

Comment: I would guess that it was because you didn't show any ideas... (saying "I cannot write my idea, because it's trivial" is no excuse, it seems). Just to let it clear, I didn't downvoted... (if I had given a downvote, I wouldn't even bother writing an answer `:P`)

Comment: @B11b: Because unfortunately some people here believe that everyone who asks a question must to be able to offer some sort of work.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation :) no problem to give a downvote. Just, I wondered about its reason. @IvoTerek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that $A \mathrel{\triangle}B \subset (A \mathrel{\triangle}C) \cup (B \mathrel{\triangle}C)$: if $x \in A \mathrel{\triangle} B$, then $x \in A \setminus B$ or $x \in B \setminus A$. Suppose WLOG that $x \in A \setminus B$. If $x \in C$, then $x \in C \setminus B$ and hence $x \in B \mathrel{\triangle}C$ and we're done. If $x \not\in C$, then $x \in A \setminus C$ and hence $x \in A \mathrel{\triangle}C$ and we're done in the same way. Concluding:

$$A \mathrel{\triangle}B \subset (A \mathrel{\triangle}C) \cup (B \mathrel{\triangle}C) \implies P(A \mathrel{\triangle}B) \leq P(A \mathrel{\triangle}C)+P(B \mathrel{\triangle}C).$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$A \mathrel{\triangle}B= (A \mathrel{\triangle} C) \mathrel{\triangle} (C \mathrel{\triangle}B) \subset   (A \mathrel{\triangle}C) \cup (C \mathrel{\triangle}B)$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in A$ and $x \not\in B$.  If $x\in C$, $x\in B\mathrel{\triangle} C$.  If $x\not\in C$, then, since $x\in A$, $x\in A\mathrel{\triangle} C$.

Can you do the rest?

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I didn't know about \mathrel{\triangle}.  Very nice